# How to upload file into network folder in linux?

Tags: linux

I have a web application in linux. When upload file, I want to save file into a Network in another server (Linux OS). I used mount -rw command to mount folder, which I want to save my file to my local folder but I still can't upload file. How can I do?

Comment: How are you sharing the folder, NFS? And what do you mean that you "can't upload" it. Do you get an error, does it silently fail, etc? We need more details

Answer (score 1):

An excellent way of mounting a remote folder locally is via 'sshfs'

it works over the standard SSH port (22). Quick, encrypted, painless alternative to NFS

> sshfs user@example.org:/var/www/htdocs www-example

If you require access to a non-user folder:

1) You can allow root login via /etc/ssh/sshd_config (Not very secure)

2) changing permissions on the remote folder to allow access via a normal user

3) Setting up keys.

http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to just use scp:

```
scp filename.zip server:/path/to/dir/filename.zip
```

You will need to make sure you have an ssh key correctly configured so that your client machine can connect to the server machine without a password.  Try `man ssh-keygen` and `man ssh-copy-id`.

Comment: you will also need an account with exactly the same name on the remote machine, as you are not specifying account with ... artifex@server:/path/to/dir/filename.zip